# Rendering ExtJs components without panels?

Tags: javascript, extjs

Take a look at this example: http://www.extjs.com/deploy/dev/examples/multiselect/multiselect-demo.html

On it, there are components rendered against a panel. I've been searching for a way to render components without a panel, so that they are laid out against empty background directly, without any window-like panels. Is there a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do not need the panel look, you can configure it by deleting the title, and the frame.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but it depends on what you're doing.  Generically, you can render a Component to any containing element on the page (e.g., using the `renderTo` config).  However, certain types of components (like form fields) require certain types of containers/layouts (FormLayout) to render as expected.

Answer (score 0):

When I want something like a panel without the overhead, I use Container and sometimes BoxComponent.  I think of these components as light-weight panels; it turns out they are typically no more than a DIV.  In earlier versions of Ext JS one had to include an autoEl parameter when configuring or else...